# how can i delete item in recyclerView from db

Tags: android, database

this in my db

```
 public void deleteItem(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_PLACE, ID + "=?" + id, null);
    }
```

Comment: great, this is how you can delete some rows from your db table

Comment: in my recycler i bean call to the helper to delete and its not delete my row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the notifyItemRemoved(int position) method to tell the RecyclerView that the element at this position has been removed. The code you have only deletes the element from the database but the RecyclerView needs to be told to update the data as well.

The other option is to delete this item from your backing list and reload your Adapter using swapAdapter(newAdapter, false) which tells RecyclerView to reuse existing ViewHolder